# Почему мы не можем использовать модификатор "inline" когда работаем с Kotlin и ViewBinding в AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

У моей функции есть модификатор inline, а также она принимает параметр с crossinline модификатором. Но когда я пытаюсь заменить код в ней на ViewBinding, выводится следующее сообщение "Public-API Inline function cannot access non-public-API"

Comment: Здесь вопросы следует задавать на русском языке.

Comment: Извините, не обратил внимание.

Answer (score 0):

public inline функции не могут использовать непубличный API, поскольку, если они встроены, эти непубличные ссылки на API нарушат ограничения доступа на месте вызова.

[KotlinDoc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-published-api/)

Comment: "Сайт вызова" звучит странно :) Ссылка скорее вот эта по теме https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#public-inline-restrictions